# Storing API data in global variables jquery

Tags: jquery, json, geolocation

```
var position= $.getJSON( "http://ip-api.com/json", function( data ) {
  position =  {lon: data.lon, lat: data.lat}
  return position;
});
 var lon = position.lon;
 var lat = position.lat;
console.log(lon);
```

How can I getvariables from async functions to become global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, this is work good way

```
window.onload = function() {
set();
setTimeout(get,2000);;
};
function set() {
$.getJSON( "http://ip-api.com/json",function(data) {
var position = {"lon": data.lon,"lat": data.lat};
document.getElementById("id").value= position;
});
}
function get() {
var k = $("#id").val();
console.log(k);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I made the ajax function to not be async like this:

```
$.ajax({
async: false,
url: "http://ip-api.com/json",
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
position = { lon: data.lon, lat: data.lat };
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use var when declaring variables that you you want to be global